# What process detects whether two I2C master devices send conflicting messages?

Tags: i2c

I'm curious - if two I2C master devices are sending commands or messages at the same time that conflict, is there any process that detects it ? What does that process do ?

Comment: I2C is an open-drain bus, so arbitration automatically works at the datalink bit level. Whichever master is transmitting a '0' automatically wins arbitration, and whichever master is trying (unsuccessfully) to transmit a '1' automatically loses. The master has to sense that SDA is 0 when the master wanted it to be 1. Lower-numbered slave device addresses get priority. This is covered in Philips' I2C Specification document.

Answer (score 2):

I<sup>2</sup>C (**I**nter-**I**C **C**ommunications) has a data line 'SDA' and a clock line 'SCL'.  Both of these are pulled high by a resistor and low by a device.

In most systems you only have a single master so the master sends a command and waits for a reply it knows what reply it is looking for so you should not get any data clashes.

In a multi-master system however two devices can talk at the same time and it is the responsibility of each to make sure they do not clash.

To achieve this every device constantly monitors 'SCL' and 'SDA'. Only masters pull the 'SCL' line low.

If a device is transmitting and it sees either line it is controlling as low when it is not pulling it low it knows there is a data clash and bows out to let the other device complete its message.  Once complete it can transmit its message again.

I have never designed a multi master system so I am not sure how well this works in practice but given each message from a master starts by referencing an I<sup>2</sup>C address I would expect the data clash to be spotted early and dealt with gracefully.

For a more detailed explanation see the [I2C Specification from NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the nice summary of Warren: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf see 3.1.8 Arbitration. In case of a situation where two masters (or controllers in the doc) start at the same time.

Edit: quote from the mentioned paper:

> Arbitration, like synchronization, refers to a portion of the protocol
> required only if more than one controller is used in the system.
> Targets are not involved in the arbitration procedure. A controller
> may start a transfer only if the bus is free. Two controllers may
> generate a START condition within the minimum hold time (tHD;STA) of
> the START condition which results in a valid START condition on the
> bus. Arbitration is then required to determine which controller will
> complete its transmission.
>
> Arbitration proceeds bit by bit. During every bit, while SCL is HIGH,
> each controller checks to see if the SDA level matches what it has
> sent. This process may take many bits. Two controllers can actually
> complete an entire transaction without error, as long as the
> transmissions are identical. The first time a controller tries to send
> a HIGH, but detects that the SDA level is LOW, the controller knows
> that it has lost the arbitration and turns off its SDA output driver.
> The other controller goes on to complete its transaction.
>
> No information is lost during the arbitration process. A controller
> that loses the arbitration can generate clock pulses until the end of
> the byte in which it loses the arbitration and must restart its
> transaction when the bus is free.